# Apply default prop values to components from library

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a UI widgets library, let's call it `ui-library`

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Button } from 'ui-library';

const ButtonHOC = ({
  id,
  resourceId,
  isEnabled = true,
  onClick,
  size = Button.size.NORMAL,
  type = Button.type.DEFAULT,
  className = '',
}) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    onClick();
  };

  return (
    <Button id={idGenerator(id)} disabled={!isEnabled} type={type} size={size} onClick={handleClick} className={className}>
      <Res id={resourceId} />
    </Button>
  );
};

ButtonHOC.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  resourceId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  isEnabled: PropTypes.bool,
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  size: PropTypes.string,
  type: PropTypes.string,
  className: PropTypes.string,
};

export default ButtonHOC;
```

Very often, I need/want to wrap components so that they have default values in order so simplify their usage.

I do this via HOC. However, as Michael Jackson explained, HOC have their drawbacks (no PropTypes validation, PropTypes can be overriden etc.).

Is it possible to do the same in a different way, **WITHOUT HOC** (like `render-props` or sth else)?

Thanks

Comment: you can use OR operator for all props say `disabled={!isEnabled || false}`

Comment: I posted an answer and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, `size`, `type` and `className` props will be applied with the default props of `Button` component.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Button } from 'ui-library';

const ButtonHOC = ({
  id,
  resourceId,
  isEnabled,
  size,
  type,
  className
}) => (
  <Button id={idGenerator(id)} disabled={!isEnabled} {...rest}>
    <Res id={resourceId} />
  </Button>
);

ButtonHOC.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  resourceId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  isEnabled: PropTypes.bool,
  size: PropTypes.string,
  type: PropTypes.string,
  className: PropTypes.string,
};

ButtonHoc.defaultProps = {
  isEnabled: true,
  size: null,
  type: null,
  className: null,
}

export default ButtonHOC;
```

**UPDATE: The default values of size, type and className props should be already defined `Button` component of `ui-library`**

Comment: I added more info to the question, i.e.: Is it possible to do the same in a different way, WITHOUT HOC

Comment: I see, by the way what is `<Res>` component inside `Button` component?

Comment: It is just some other component, it is missing in imports cos I skipped some parts of the code.